# How can I use custom parameters in [permalinks] section in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I am setting up the `[permalinks]` section of the `config.toml` in a Hugo website. I want to use more values than the ones [provided here](https://gohugo.io/content-management/urls/#permalink-configuration-values).

I've tried

```
[permalinks]
post = "/p/:year:month:day:hour:minute"
```

but it's throwing an error saying it's malformed probably because `:hour` and `:minute` aren't valid. I mainly wanted to use these two in the permalink

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Hugo v0.60.0 has been released and with it (and later versions) you can use something like this to accomplish what you asked for:

```
[permalinks]
post = "/p/:year:month:day:15:04/"
```

In Go and Hugo, you can think of the reference datetime as:

```
01/02 15:04:05 2006 MST
```

This is why `hour` is `:15` and `minute` is `:04` in the permalink. Info about date and time in Go is at https://golang.org/pkg/time/.

Below is my original answer...

According to [Notes release notes 0.60 · Issue #6490 · gohugoio/hugo · GitHub](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6490), this will be possible soon. Here's the relevant excerpt:

- Permalink config an dates: 6489 [*]

I want this too!

[*] [Support Go time format strings in permalinks by look · Pull Request #6489 · gohugoio/hugo · GitHub](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/pull/6489)

Comment: Cool, when does version 0.60 drop?

Comment: I have no idea but I bet it will be a while because there is a mention of 0.59.2 in [Hugo Issues](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue). We are at 0.59.1 now